# Formatting JSON object for display in table

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have an ajax query which returns some JSON and puts it into a table. 
The JSON is in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Donald",
    "lastname": "Duck",
    "email": "quack@gmail.com",
    "skills": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "chemistry"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The 'skills' are coming back as an object because they have multiple values, but this means that they will not display in my table. I have tried to convert them to string using

JSON.Stringify(data[i].skills, null, " ") but it makes the whole table disappear. Any ideas on how I can get the data to show in the table?

Here is my function-

```
function getAgents() {


     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://127.0.0.1:3010/admin-api/v1/123/agents/",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

             // fill a table with the JSON
           $("table.mytable").html("<tr><th></th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>  <th>Queues</th></tr>"  );

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   $("table.mytable").append("<tr><td>" + "<input type = 'checkbox'" + "</td><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + data[i].skills +  "</td></tr>"  );
}

         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
   }
```

Have also tried-

```
$("table.mytable").html("<tr><th></th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Queues</th></tr>"  );

              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var skills = data[i].skills;

                  for(var j = 0; j < skills.length; j++) {
                  var skill = skills[j];



    $("table.mytable").append("<tr><td>" + "<input type = 'checkbox'" + "</td><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + data[i].skill + "</td></tr>");
}
}

         },
```

Comment: i.e because you have an error. `Stringify` should be `stringify` http://jsfiddle.net/95ypA/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for me either way? Using the lower case stringify doesnt make the table disappear, but it just says undefined for the array values!

Comment: What do you mean by not contructing my html properly? Very much a newbie.

Comment: sorry, your html is fine. did you check the fiddle in my earlier comment. see if you see any errors in your console. It works for me in the fiddle..

Comment: No errors in console-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `JSON.Stringify`; it should be `JSON.stringify`. Did you check your console for errors? Simply spitting the JSON out isn't too user-friendly, though. Is that what you want?

You're going to have to iterate over each individual skill and then insert that into the table in a format that you see fit (perhaps you can use an un-ordered list):

```
var $table = jQuery("table");
$table.append(jQuery("tr")
    .append(
        jQuery("th").text("First Name"))
    .append(
        jQuery("th").text("LastName")) ... //and so on 
)

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var $tr = jQuery("tr");
    $tr.append(
        jQuery("td").text(data[i].firstname})
    ).append(
        jQuery("td").text(data[i].lastname)
    )...

    var skills = data[i].skills;
    var $ul = jQuery("ul");

    for(var j = 0; j < skills.length; j++) {
        var skill = skills[j];

        $ul.append(jQuery("li").text(skill.name));
    }

    $tr.append(jQuery("td").append($ul));
}
```

Comment: That looks really good, but where do I put this iteration? Do I nest it within my original for statement?

Comment: Yes, you would have to nest it.

Comment: That makes all my data disappear, see edit- I am probably doing it wrong, very new to this

Comment: @bookthief You cannot put the code that generates each row (corresponding to each value of `i`) inside the loop that iterates over each skill. You have to do it separately. First generate the code for the table row, then generate the rest of the data for the skill.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by that?